# Get data from SQL datebase and return as string

Tags: c#, string, tostring, sqlconnection

Need help to get the 1st row record and return record as string in the `<< >>` after `while()` loop.
There are a lot of columns in one row, I'm having a problem to declare it as string st? like usually `string st = new string()` please help to correct it

Thanks

```
public string Get_aodIdeal(string SubmittedBy)
{
    String errMsg = "";
    Guid? rguid = null;
    int isOnContract = 0;
    int isFreeMM = 0;
    string _FileName;
    DateTime InstallDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    string FileDate = ToYYYYMMDD(DateTime.Now);
    errMsg = "Unknown Error.";

    SqlConnection conn = null; SqlCommand cmd = null;
    string st = null;

    conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iDeal"].ConnectionString);
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string SQL = "select TOP 1 * from table1 Order by SubmittedOn desc";
    SqlDataAdapter sqd = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, conn);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 1200;
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader sqr;
    //sqd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Submitted", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PostID;
    sqr = sqd.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqr.Read())
st = new string{
    rguid = cmd.Parameters["@rguid"].Value as Guid?,
                ridno = int.Parse(sqr["ridno"].ToString()),
                SubmittedOn= DateTime.Parse(sqr["SubmittedOn"].ToString()),
                SubmittingHost = sqr["SubmittingHost"].ToString(),
                ServiceAgreementNo = sqr["ServiceAgreementNo"].ToString(),
                DocumentID = sqr["DocumentID"].ToString(),
                Source = sqr["Source"].ToString(),
                FileName = sqr["FileName"].ToString(),
                FileType = sqr["FileType"].ToString(),
                FileDate = DateTime.Parse(sqr["FileDate"].ToString()),
                InstallTime = DateTime.Parse(sqr["InstallTime"].ToString()),
                CalenderCode = cmd.Parameters["CalenderCode"].Value as Guid,
                isFreeMM = bool.Parse(sqr["isFreeMM"].ToString()),
                isOnContract = bool.Parse(sqr["isOnContract"].ToString()),
                isProcessed = bool.Parse(sqr["isProcessed"].ToString()),
                ProcessedByFullName = sqr["ProcessedByFullName"].ToString(),
                isDelete = bool.Parse(sqr["isDelete"].ToString()),
                version = int.Parse(sqr["Version"].ToString()),
                LastUpdatedBy = DateTime.Parse(sqr["LastUpdatedBy"].ToString()),
                LastUpdatedOn = DateTime.Parse(sqr["LastUpdatedOn"].ToString()),
                shopGuid = sqr["shopGuid"].ToString(),
                MacID = sqr["MacID"].ToString(),
                MSISDN = sqr["MSISDN"].ToString()
}
```

Comment: If there are a lot of columns, which column do you want to return from the method and why don't you use `ExecuteScalar` instead of the `SqlDataReader`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter im quite confuse with sql also there are many way so is there any recommandations? how to i get all the columns and return as string?

Comment: If you fill the data into datatable using dataadapter, I think it's so easy to get the data row by row in string format.

Comment: @xSea: create a custom class which has a lot of properties, like `string ServiceAgreementNo`, `bool isOnContract` or `LastUpdatedOn`. Then initialize it in the `while`-loop(you could also use a single `sqr.Read()` because you know that there is only one). Then return this custom class instead of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a StringBuilder for this purpose as like the following:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder= new StringBuilder(); 
while (sqr.Read())
{
    strBuilder.AppendFormat("PostID  : {0}{1}",sqr["PostID"].ToString(),Environment.NewLine);
    strBuilder.AppendFormat("dateposted  : {0}{1}",sqr["dateposted"].ToString(),Environment.NewLine);
    // And so on Build your string
}
```

Finally the `strBuilder.ToString()` will give you the required string. But More smarter way is Create a Class with necessary properties and an Overrided .ToString method for display the output.

Let `AodIdeal` be a class with an overrided `ToString()` method. And Let me   defined it like the following :

```
public class AodIdeal
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string  dateposted { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    // Rest of properties here

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder ObjectStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        ObjectStringBuilder.AppendFormat("PostID  : {0}{1}", PostID, Environment.NewLine);
        ObjectStringBuilder.AppendFormat("dateposted  : {0}{1}",dateposted, Environment.NewLine);
        ObjectStringBuilder.AppendFormat("Source  : {0}{1}", Source, Environment.NewLine);

        // and so on
        return ObjectStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you can create an object of the class(let it be objAodIdeal), and make use of its properties instead for the local variables. And finally `objAodIdeal.ToString()` will give you the required output.

**Example usage**

```
AodIdeal objAodIdeal= new AodIdeal(); 
while (sqr.Read())
{
    objAodIdeal.PostID = int.Parse(sqr["PostID"].ToString());
    objAodIdeal.dateposted= sqr["dateposted"].ToString();
    // assign rest of properties
}
string requiredString= objAodIdeal.ToString();
```